# Use numpy to load data from csv to a single list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, csv

I have a csv file called data.csv and this is what it contains:

```
8.84,17.22,13.22,3.84
3.99,11.73,19.66,1.27
16.14,18.72,7.43,11.09
```

What I want to do is to load all of it into a single list that looks like this:

```
[8.84,17.22,13.22,3.84,3.99,11.73,19.66,1.27,16.14,18.72,7.43,11.09]
```

The script I wrote using numpy is

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt(data.csv,delimiter=',')
print(data)
```

But what this gives me is a 3 x 4 numpy array

```
[[  8.84  17.22  13.22   3.84]
 [  3.99  11.73  19.66   1.27]
 [ 16.14  18.72   7.43  11.09]]
```

Comment: Then just do `data.flatten()` or reshape it using `np.reshape(data, data.shape[0]*data.shape[1])`

Comment: `np.loadtxt(data.csv,delimiter=',').reshape(-1)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the numpy array to a list of arrays and then use list comprehension to flatten it.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')
expected_output = [item for sub_list in list(data) for item in sub_list]

print(expected_output)
```

Comment: This is really not the best approach. It probably is even worse than reading the file line by line.